# Get folder by regex in `list.files()`?

Tags: r

I want to get all `*.txt` files in the directory `../20180101_Folder`.

My code:

```
theFiles <- list.files(
  path = "../*Folder",
  pattern = "*.txt",
  full.names = TRUE
)
```

But `theFiles` ends up being `NULL`. How do I make `theFiles` equal to a list of all `.txt` files in the specified directory?

Comment: if doable, you should probably move all the *_folder into a main folder, and then use "recursive = TRUE" to get all the files in all subfolders

Comment: @G5W That worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

list.files will expand ~ in a path, but will not expand wild-cards like *.
To use those you need

```
path=Sys.glob("../*Folder")
```